# Integration by parts on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary,  $f,g \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $X$ be a smooth vector field. Is it true that we can integration by parts with respect to the differentiation with $X$, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{M}X(f) g = -\int_{M}f X(g)
\end{equation*}
In other words, does the Stoke's Theorem hold for the expression $\int_{M}X(fg)$ ?

Comment: Is the manifold orientable?

Comment: Yes. You can add all the nice properties about the manifold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This integration by parts identity does not hold in general. The divergence theorem
$$
\int_M\operatorname{div}(X)\mu_g=\int_{\partial M}g(N,X)\mu_{\iota^*g}
$$
(Where $\mu_g$ is the Riemannian measure and $\mu_{\iota^*g}$ is the induced measure on the boundary), as well as the product rule for divergences
$$
\operatorname{div}(fX)=X(f)+f\operatorname{div}(X)
$$
Holds for any compact Riemannian manifold $M$ ($M$ need not be oriented). Applying these to to an $M$ without boundary, starting with the expression
$$
\int_M\operatorname{div}(fgX)\mu_g=0
$$
we arrive at the integration by parts formula with an extra term.
$$
\int_MX(f)g\mu_g+\int_MfX(g)\mu_g+\int_Mfg\operatorname{div}(X)\mu_g=0
$$
The third term does not vanish in general (e.g. choose $X$ with nonvanishing divergence and let $fg=\operatorname{div}(X)$). However, it does give rise to a special case: integration by parts works exactly as written in the question provided $X$ is solenoidal.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I'm actually working with Killing vector fields (which are divergence free) so it seems like the integration by parts formula does hold for them!

Answer (score 4):

You define for a vector field $X$ on $M$, $\operatorname{div}X\operatorname{dvol}=d\iota_X\operatorname{dvol}$ where $\operatorname{dvol}$ is the associated volume form of the Riemannian manifold.

Note that $\operatorname{div}X\operatorname{dvol}=\mathcal L_X\operatorname{dvol}$

$\operatorname{div}fX\operatorname{dvol}=\mathcal L_{fX}\operatorname{dvol}=Xf\operatorname{dvol}+f\mathcal L_X\operatorname{dvol}$

Since $\operatorname{div}X\operatorname{dvol} $ is exact by definition, we get $$\int_M \operatorname{div}fX\operatorname{dvol}=0$$ $$\int_MXf\operatorname{dvol}+f\mathcal L_X\operatorname{dvol}=0$$ $$\implies \int_MXf\operatorname{dvol}=-\int_Mf\mathcal L_X\operatorname{dvol}$$